# Batch file unable to edit the HOSTS file

Tags: windows-7, batch, hosts

I have a host edit that I need to deploy for a department. Rather than add that to their current image I was planning to add that as a post deployment script. I cast about looking for a script to edit the host file and found a simple one that suits my purposes. However it doesn't seem to elevate the script to admin even when I right click the .bat and tell it to run as admin. I'm a bit confused.

The script looks like it will work properly, but when it gets to the step of appending the host entry it fails with an access denial.

Testing on Windows 7. Using my normal account as well as a domain admin account.

Comment: Look into using the `PSExec` utility with your domain credentials. If each user will have the same host file, I would opt to replace it rather than edit and save it.

Comment: Ensure the HOSTS file isn't being marked as read-only (or actively protected against changes) by anti-malware utilities...   Can you provide a copy of the batch file's contents?

Comment: I could do the replace, as all users will have the same hosts change. That's probably actually easier.I'll have to image up a machine to test it and see how that works since my PC has some specialized hosts edits.

I could try disabling my AV, let me see how that works, because it may be stopping the script. Didn't think of that, and I really should have. 

Failing all of the above, I'll post in the script contents since it's just 4 lines.

Comment: AV was stopping me. As soon as I killed it the batch executed properly. Man I feel dumb.

Comment: Yeah, I've run into that battle before as well. ;)  I"ll put it in as an actual answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the HOSTS file isn't being marked as read-only (or actively protected against changes) by resident anti-malware utilities.